# Cisco AnyConnect connecting but no unix commands responding on Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ssh, vpn

After being successfully connected to the VPN with Cisco Anyconnect client 4.8.03052, I can open some intranet application in the browser. 
The problem is : I can connect to some servers with ssh sessions, but unix commands are NOT responding after that.
Can you help me please. 
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 64-bits.

Thanks in advance